# Convert traditional loop of invoking weclient into non blocking way

Tags: java, spring, webclient, spring-webflux, project-reactor

I am new to reactive programming and I want to transform the following code into non blocking way.

For the sake of simplicity, I created a sample pseudo code based from my original code. Any help will be appreciated.

```
 public Mono<Response> getResponse(List<Provider> providers) {

    for (Provider provider : providers) {
        Response response = provider.invokeHttpCall().block();

        if(response.getMessage() == "Success") {
            return Mono.just(response);
        }

        continue;
    }

    return Mono.empty();
}
```

`provider.invokeHttpCall()` method

```
    @Override
    public Mono<Response> invokeHttpCall(){
        WebClient webClient = WebClient.create();
        
        
        return webClient.post()
                .uri("/provider").accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .retrieve()
                .bodyToMono(Response.class);
    }
```

I tried several tactics to implement this, but still no luck. Either all providers are invoked or I need to block the webclient thread.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```java
Flux.fromIterable(providers)
    .concatMap(Provider::invokeHttpCall) // ensures providers are called sequentially
    .filter(response -> response.getMessage().equals("Success"))
    .next()
```

Answer (score 0):

reactive is a kind of Stream. Please think it as a Stream and program it reactively.

I give you such followed code.

1. Firstly, use `Flux.fromIterable()` to create a flux stream from a List.
2. Next, use `flatmap()` and Lambda fuction to emit the `invoke` into another new thread.
3. use method `filterWhen()` and Lambda to get the "Success" response and just get the first "Success" elements. See [filterwhen](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Flux.html#filterWhen-java.util.function.Function-filterwhen) api Doc.
4. Finally, just use `Mono.from()` to wrap the `Flux` and then return the `Mono` type.

```java
public Mono<Response> getResponse(List<Provider> providers) {

    return Mono.from(Flux.fromIterable(providers)
                .flatmap(provider -> 
                    Mono.defer(() -> provider.invokeHttpCall())
                .filterWhen(response -> response.getMessage() == "Success");
}
```

if you want to see result and `println()`.
Just use `.subsribe()` method to excute it.

```java
getResponse.subsribe(System.out::println);
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. The problem in the above code is that all providers will be invoke. I only want to proceed on the next iteration if the current provider response does not qualified in the specified condition.

Comment: Just to add `provider.invokeHttpCall()` is a webclient call. It will use another thread to execute the http call.

Comment: Hi @dyy.alex. Your code is working. If I may ask before I tag it as the accepted answer, is there a possible solution without blocking the webclient thread?

Comment: @JeromeRyanVillamor , of course there are. But first, you need to overwrite your syn-method provider.invokeHttpCall() as an asynchronous-method. And second, you need to use reactor to wrapper the asynchronous method in order return a Mono or Flux type. If you think my solution is well, i am happy to accept upvote :)